# Add data to the application.hbs template in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to do something which should be simple but I'm note sure it's even possible...

I want to add data into the default template `application.hbs` of Ember.js for exemple have the current date in my footer.

Should I do it with a component ? I tried to pass data throught the `index.js` route but nothing show up :s

My `index.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    const data = [
      {rate: 1.23},
      {rate: 1.23},
      {rate: 1.23}
    ];
    return data;
  }
});
```

My `application.hbs`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      {{outlet}}
      {{#each model as |rate|}}
        <p>{{rate.rate}}</p>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting such these things in component is a good practice.

But for your case, you need to put rate data in application route, not index route.

They are different.

Comment: A weird thing happens when I try to just pass a string to the model it's not show up but when I pass an array with objects inside it's working...

Comment: @Hugo-Contreras Because you iterate over an array and get `.rate` attribute of that in template

Comment: I also changed my template with just ``{{data}}``

Comment: @Hugo-Contreras Don't forget about iteration. You can iterate on an array not string

Comment: My bad in my template I was calling {{data}} but to work I had to use {{model}}